# Angular 4 .Net Core WebApi on Ubuntu not serving bundles

Tags: angular, ubuntu, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm attempting to host an Angular 4 CLI project using .Net Core 2 on Ubuntu running Nginx.  When I start the application, I can hit the hosting page, but when the browser attempts to download the various bundles, it fails with 500 errors.  Everything seems to work fine on Windows.

My configuration in sites-enabled for nginx is

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                try_files $uri $uri/ wwwroot/$uri /wwwroot/$uri /wwwroot/index.html;
        }
}
```

My Configure Method in my Startup.cs class looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }


      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
      {
        await next();
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
        {
          context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
          await next();
        }
      })
      .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } })

      .UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed a previous edit before I posted.  The Configure method above also requires ".UseStaticFiles()" before ".UseMvc()" to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my nginx configuration. In my sites-enabled/default file, I didn't specify the root path.

The fix was to add the following line under listen 80;

root /var/website/wwwroot;

Answer (score 0):

The final nginx configuration that worked the best for me was the following:

server {
        listen 80;

```
    root /var/website/wwwroot/;
    index index.html;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}

Hopefully this helps save someone a bit of time